# Hover event for Zero Clipboard?

Tags: zeroclipboard

I have implemented zeroclipboard.

I need to add a style to a parent div when zeroclipboard is hovered over, unfortunately I cannot find a way to do this with CSS.

So I have resorted to JS.

I have tried the jquery .hover method, but no luck, I've looked at the docs for zeroclipboard but cannnot find an event that triggers on hover.

How can I fire a JS event when a user hovers over the zeroclipboard SWF?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#global-zeroclipboard-html-bridge").hover(function() {
    $("#btn-copy").css('background', 'black');
}, function() {
    $("#btn-copy").css('background', 'white');
});
```